# How to access std::tuple<double,double> from c++ in python

Tags: python, ctypes

I defined a tuple function in c++, `std::tuple<double,double>`, does anyone know how to access the return variables in `<double,double>` with `ctype.restype` method in python?

I'm using `restype = ctypes.c_double` but that doesn't work.

Comment: Pretty sure this is beyond `ctypes` capabilities; the internal structure of `std::tuple` isn't explicitly documented, so you can't guarantee anything about how to read the return value. You could *try* `restype = c_types.c_double * 2` and hope `std::tuple<double,double>` is returned in the same way as a size two C array of `double`s, but even if it works, I wouldn't count on it being portable.

Comment: It's `ctypes` not `cpptypes`.  C++ doesn't have a standard binary interface, unlike C.  [SWIG](http://www.swig.org) can do it, but you have to compile a Python extension.

Comment: @ShadowRanger, you are right, I tried, it is not working, the error message is the restype must be type, callable or object

Comment: @MarkTolonen, could you please give more clarification on what you saying？

Comment: `ctypes` gives you the ability to call C functions, not C++.  C has well-defined rules for inter-operating with other languages.  C++ does not.  `std::tuple<double,double>`  isn't supported by `ctypes`.  SWIG is a tool to generate an extension for Python (and other languages) that can convert a C++ interface to a C interface and expose that standard interface to Python.